# Material UI Slider with React hook form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm having a hard time integrating material Ui Slider with React hook form. It's not registering the values. It's printing the value as undefined on console.log. Got an idea where I might be wrong?

```
  <Controller
        render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
          <CustomSlider
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            max={60}
            marks={marks}
            className={classes.slider}
            defaultValue={10}
          />
        )}
        control={control}
        name="slider"
      />
```

Comment: Please can you show where you call your console.log ?

Comment: I'm using the watch method

Answer (score 2):

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-controller-qsd8r?file=/src/Mui.js:2973-3369) made by author of react-hook-form that contains many examples. Mui integration is also made.

According to example, you are supposted to do something like this:

```
<Controller
          name="MUI_Slider"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={[0, 10]}
          render={(props) => (
            <Slider
              {...props}
              onChange={(_, value) => {
                props.onChange(value);
              }}
              valueLabelDisplay="auto"
              max={10}
              step={1}
            />
          )}
        />
```

Another question is in which part of your code are you trying to console.log() values.
You can use watch() method or

```
<button Click={() => console.log(getValues())}>get values</button>
```

Comment: I get an error props.onChange is not a function. I guess I'm using react-hook-form v7 while this is for v6

Comment: This issue was solved once I used field instead of props. Thank you!!